# When using C++ to connect to a database via ADO, the data type of _bstr_t automatically sets the Chinese characters to garbled

Tags: c++, sql-server

The following code is not printed correctly.

```
_bstr_t a = "select * from [我$A6:G999]";

std::wcout << a << std::endl;
```

The printed results are as follows:
`select * from [?A6:G999]`

I checked and found that any Chinese characters stored in _bstr_t, or some special symbols will be changed to garbled. But if I convert the characters from UTF_8 to GBK, the problem is gone. Is this problem a bug? If so, what should I do?

Comment: I would assume that the strint literal itself has a problem with that symbol. You could try to add a L in front of it (  L"...." ) to make it a wide string literal.

Comment: Agreed, this is not a problem with `_bstr_t` itself. You simply can't store `我` in a `char` string like you are doing, you need to encode it as UTF-8 or other `char`-compatible encoding.  However, `_bstr_t` only supports `char` strings that are encoded in the user's locale.

Answer (score 0):

Are you configuring your code to output Unicode code points?

For example, the following works on macOS when `std::wcout.imbue()` is called but not when it is skipped...

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include <locale>

int main() {
    std::wcout.imbue(std::locale("en_US.utf-8"));
    std::wcout << L"select * from [\u6211$A6:G999]" << std::endl;
    std::wcout << L"select * from [我$A6:G999]" << std::endl;
}
```